# Internet Explorer X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM not working in IE 11 and Edge

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iframe, xss, x-frame-options

I am having an issue using `X-Frame-Options` to embed one site as an iFrame into another (different domains) with IE 11 and Edge.  My research and experience indicate that IE doesn't yet support CSP Level 2 frame-ancestors, so I must use `X-Frame-Options`.

I have added the response header 
`X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://<mysite>.com`
to the site that needs to be embedded.

These are secured sites so I am unable to provide real URLs to this community.

When I launch the main site, which contains an iFrame with content from the second site, I am able to see the `X-Frame-Options` header in the response for the iframe content and it looks to be applied correctly. However, IE indicates "...modified this page to help prevent cross-site scripting" and my frame contains only the `#` symbol.

Due to timing and internal IT delays, I am unable to have both sites hosted in the same domain.

Can anyone help to explain what I did wrong in implementing `X-Frame-Options` or if there is another option to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Please check browser support for `ALLOW-FROM` [https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet#Browser_Support](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet#Browser_Support)

Comment: OWASP indicates support for Allow-From starting with IE9 and up.  My issue is in IE 11 and Edge, on Win 8 and 10.  It may be an issue on Win7, but I haven't been able to test that yet.

Answer (score 1):

IE 11 not following [standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options), which means can not use "*", so have to give domain name with http/https.

```
  def cors_set_access_control_headers
    headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
    headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "GET"
    headers["Access-Control-Request-Method"] = "*"
    headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
    headers["X-Frame-Options"] = "ALLOW-FROM http://172.16.1.159"
    headers["X-XSS-Protection"] = "0"
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue wasn't related to frames.  The framed content had the same XSS error/note when accessed directly vs through an embedded iframe.  The timing of the error showing threw me off since it was coincidental to the implementation of CSP level 2 frame-ancestors.

I have opened a case with MS to determine what in the content the XSS engine doesn't like and have had to disable the XSS in IE browsers with the X-XSS-Protection:0 response header.